# Meteor, ClientStorage- TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using the [ostrio:cstorage](https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/cstorage) package like so (for testing):

```
import { check } from 'meteor/check'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import {Tasks} from './collections.js'
import { ClientStorage, clientStorage } from 'meteor/ostrio:cstorage';

Meteor.methods({
  'vote.check'(tipId) {
  //check(tipId, String);

  // we want to use a date with a 1-day granularity
  var startOfDay = new Date;
  startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  console.log("In vote.check:"+tipId);

  clientStorage.has('aaaa');
},
```

But I always get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined" - can anybody tell me why? I really have no idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
ClientStorage.has('aaaa');
```

The lower case version defines a class; to use it you need to create a new variable.

```
csCookies = new clientStorage('cookies');
csCookies.has('aaaa');
```

You shouldn't need to import both `ClientStorage` and `clientStorage`. The Uppercase one deals with cookies/local storage transparently.